# Replacing null values for multiple columns in a table with a constant value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to run a script that replaces all null values in a table with a constant value in MS Access 2007. I am fully aware that this can be done using an update query. But the requirement that I need to do that for all columns in one click. I figured that find/replace can do this, but still I would rather minimize any manual work in the process.

I tried using this code but when I try to run it, it just doesn't do anything. It doesn't even trigger an error.

```
Sub replacingnulls()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("testtable", dbOpenTable)

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
            rs.Edit

        For Each fld In rs.Fields

            If IsNull(fld.Value) Then
                fld.Value = 555

            End If
        Next fld
        rs.MoveNext
  Loop
Else
    MsgBox ("There are no records")
End If

rs.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `rs.Update` to save the changes you made to the current record before moving to the next record.

```vb
Next fld
rs.Update ' <-- add this
rs.MoveNext
```

Instead of looping through the table rows and then through each field within each row, you could execute one `UPDATE` per field.

```vb
Const cstrTable As String = "testtable"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strUpdate As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs(cstrTable)
For Each fld In tdf.Fields
    ' Access will complain if you attempt an UPDATE on an autonumber field,
    ' so skip field with dbAutoIncrField attribute
    If Not ((fld.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField) = dbAutoIncrField) Then
        strUpdate = "UPDATE [" & cstrTable & "] SET [" & fld.Name & _
            "] = 555 WHERE [" & fld.Name & "] Is Null;"
        'Debug.Print strUpdate
        db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
    End If
Next
```

Beware that code will attempt to replace all Nulls with 555 regardless of the field's datatype.  If all the fields are plain numbers, that may be fine.  However a Date/Time field with Null would become *Jul 8 1901 00:00:00*.  OTOH, your recordset approach would do the same thing ... so if it's OK there, it should be OK here, too.

Comment: Thank you so much HansUp. It solved my problem. Appreciate your help.